# Close the app.config file after reading

Tags: c#, app-config

My "app" is being hijacked by a monitoring service. After it dies, for some reason the app.config file is considered still in use, so I can't make changes.

The only thing I can do is rename the existing file, and save a new file with the old name.

This is not an interactive app, so I want to simply want to use notepad to make changes in the file between runs.

Comment: Tt's probably your application that's locking it?  What type of application is it?

Comment: Are you able to confirm if a specific service is using the file or your a shadow of your app? Do you modify the app.config within your app?

Comment: I don't modify it. How can I tell what's using it?

Comment: If you have access to the server, you could use a tool called ProcExplorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would try:

- Use [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) to figure out what service or process holds a handle to your file and "unlock" it
- Try [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). In menu go to *Find > Find handle or DLL*, search for your .config file and figure out what process is "taking a lock" on the file

Once you figure out what's causing this, check if you can somehow add an exception for your file, so that it's not trying to open this config file - very unlikely but an AV process may do that. Other solutions is to kill a misbehaving 3rd party app and start it once you finished editing config file.

Double check that your app was actually killed and no longer runs. Use process explorer or default task manager (or any other similar tool on non-Windows OS).

Comment: I'll try those things, but if it's the monitor holding the file, I can't kill it. It's a critical process.

Comment: @LeeLouviere you can try and add an exception to the monitor, if you have control over it. Otherwise there is not much you can do. Alternative would be to write a virus-like application to disarm the monitor, but you probably don't want to do that.